# Which is syscall, sys_open or open?

Tags: system-calls, strace

I think `sys_open` is the canonical syscall,

that is,those prefixed with `sys_`.

but `strace` which is supposed to log all syscalls, outputs `open` as the syscall(non prefixed version),and I'm confused...

Which one is syscall at all??

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Brian W. Kernighan and Rob Pike, from “The UNIX Programming Environment”, page 44:

> Programs retrieve the data in a file by a system call (a subroutine in the kernel) called `read`.

The system call is called `read`, and to make things simple for the programmer, the corresponding function from the C Standard Library has the same name.

The name `sys_read`, on the other hand, is only interesting to a few people, namely those who hack the kernel. Its name is just considered an implementation detail of the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about C or C++, here. Neither `sys_open()` nor `open()` is mandated by any relevant language standard to be a "system call." However, on most (all?) *NIXes (including Linux, Mac OS X, BSD, etc.) `open()` is a system call.

To my knowledge, `sys_open()` is unique to Linux, and is implemented as a layer on top of `open()`.

Comment: But in `entry.S` ,there's only `sys_open`,no `open`.Isn't all syscall supposed to be there?

Comment: Off the top of my head I don't know. Why does it matter? What are you trying to accomplish?